# Change Jupyter notebook version 4.x+ logo

Tags: python, customization, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

In IPython notebook version `2.x`, you can add logo by customizing folder `.ipython/profile_name/static/base/images/logo.png` and it will display the custom logo that we made on the header of the notebook.

In Jupyter notebook version `4.x`, we know that they move directory to `.jupyter/` instead i.e. `.jupyter/base/` and `.jupyter/custom/custom.css`. However, when I try to customize default profile in `~/.jupyter/base/images/logo.png`, I couldn't custom the logo anymore.

The question is: How to custom logo in Jupyter notebook version `4.x`. I'm wondering if there is a solution to custom Jupyter notebook logo (version `4.x`) or not. I put example snapshot of customized notebook logo in previous version `2.x` below.

[image: example]

Comment: Hi @titipat, did you try the solution here [Customize welcome page of ipython notebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27177459/customize-welcome-page-of-ipython-notebook) ? I try this solution and it works to me.

Comment: Oh nice. thanks @Eric! It almost works for me. I put the `logo.png` and added css into `custom.css`. However, my image is just too big. Probably I have to change the css file in order to make logo display properly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So here is the quick solution thanks to @Eric comment (referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27177459/customize-welcome-page-of-ipython-notebook)). First, I add `logo.png` into `.jupyter/custom/logo.png`. Then add the following lines to `.jupyter/custom/custom.css` in order to load the logo.

```
#ipython_notebook img{                                                                                        
    display:block;
    /* logo url here */
    background: url("logo.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 233px;
    height: 33px;
    padding-left: 233px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

You can also add this css tag to increase logo padding height by adding:

```
#ipython_notebook {
    height: 40px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Note:

I believe the syntax should have quotes around the file:
background: url("logo.png") no-repeat;

Answer (score 1):

Add `logo.png` into `.jupyter/custom/logo.png`. Then add the following lines to `.jupyter/custom/custom.css` in order to load the logo. With a square size I was seeing an offset of the notebook name when used titipad's CSS. This fixes it.

```
    #ipython_notebook img{                                                                                        
        display:block;
        background: url(logo.png) no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        width: 33px;
        height: 33px;
        padding-left: 33px;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    #header-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    span#login_widget {
        flex-grow: 1;
        order: 4;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }

    span#save_widget {
        flex-grow: 40;
    }
```